# Python, Pandas, SQLAlchemy: Better way instead of saving a whole dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Good day,

I would like to ask if someone knows a better - or let's say more efficient - way to save data inside a database with pandas and sqlalchemy!?

Right now the user has the possibility to upload a csv-file and pre-decide a associated customer from a select-field. This so generated dataframe get's compared to the already existing data in the database (after converting the data to a dataframe with *django_pandas: read_frame*).

Afterwards the compared - new - dataframe ist getting saved into my database with the following part of code...

**views.py**

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:12345abcde@localhost:5432/customer-db', echo=False)
conn = engine.connect()

table_name = "app_customer"
df_comp.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace')
conn.close()
```

Right now this works fine because there are only between five to ten customers with each 50 rows inside my project! So right now and in worst case the dataframe will have a maximum size of 500 rows!

And here's my question: What if my project get's bigger and there are 50 customers with each - let's say - 1.000 rows (so a dataframe with 50.000 rows)!? I'm sure it will work even though it will take much more time, but is there a more efficient way instead of always saving a complete new dataframe and replacing the old one complete?

**Notes**

- the dataframe will always contain a column with a unique number to compare the data with

Comment: You are looking for a method called "upsert" so insert if not exists, else update the row. This is being worked on in pandas and the ticket seems almost done, see [GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm going to look into this.